# Sending a form to email (AJAX, Bootstrap, Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to send a form to email with what i have below. It's a modded version of the Bootstrap Validator by 1000hz.

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    alert("not working");
  } else {
    alert("Hello! I am working");
  }
})
```

to

```
$('#form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    alert("not working");
  } else {
       var Name = $("input#Name").val();
       var Service = $("input#Service").val();
       var Email = $("input#Email").val();
       var Message = $("textarea#Message").val();
       //ajax magic
   $.ajax({
              url: "squote-send.php", // email sender file
              type: "POST",
              data: {Name: Name, Service: Service, Email: Email, Message: Message},
              cache: false,
              success: function() {
                                  $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'>");
                 $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span>")
                .append( "</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
      $('#success > .alert-success')
      .append('</div>');

  }
})
```

It is not sending?

Comment: Is there any errors in your console ?

Comment: Can you add the HTML snippet too?

Comment: actually i think i've fixed it with `event.preventDefault();` the script was reloading before the email was sent

Answer (score 1):

Simply by adding the

```
`event.preventDefault();`
```

fixed my problem.